# How is the email validation performed for ASP.NET Core Identity

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity, .net-6.0, blazor-server-side

For a Blazor Server app I scaffolded Identity and I could not find how the e-mail validation is performed when user registers.

Tried to search in all solution files for the text "Email field is not a valid" (part of the error shown message displayed) but of course it could not be as simple as that :)

Where should I look?

Update:

The validation is performed here: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.ComponentModel.Annotations/src/System/ComponentModel/DataAnnotations/EmailAddressAttribute.cs

In order to do my own validation I call my static model in             Register_New.cshtml.cs, OnPostAsync, after  if (ModelState.IsValid)

Don't know if it is the best way but I am very much a beginner with .NET

Comment: The RegisterUserModel's InputModel's Email property probably has an [Email] attribute?

Comment: correct it has, but where do they check there is an @ and so on. what I'd like to achieve is to allow only gmail and not yahoo, for example, something like that

Comment: Then create your own attribute. You don't want to use an email allow list, rather use a block list.